# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nidaqmx'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, spyder, nidaqmx

I'm using a USB-6009-NI to collect 6 digital signals. I'm using LabVIEW to collect the data but, since this is quite a burdensome task and since I need to integrate the output results with classification algorithms, I'm trying to program a piece of python code to acquire the data, process it, and feed the algorithms.

I'm using Google colab and spyder for programming and I've installed nidaqmx using pip. In spyder, I get the error `No module named 'nidaqmx'` and in colab `Could not find an installation of NI-DAQmx` (enclosed a screenshot of google colab), but I have installed the version 20.7.0 version of NI-DAQmx.

Can you please be so kind in helping me with this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ2cZ.png)

Comment: It looks like there's either some extra software or a piece of hardware you're missing.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. After installing Nidaqmx python libraries and try to import then I have the PC connected to the DAQ. I have also nidaqmx driver installed and I've been acquiring data throug Labview...

Comment: Just to add that I've found the problem and so this thread can be closed. Thanks!